# How to update a fork from it's original via the Github API

Tags: github-api

I've created a fork of a GitHub repository via the GitHub API. Now, later on, I want to pull any updates from the origin repository into the fork. This should always be a fast-forward in my use case. I have read access to the origin repository and read-write to the fork.

I thought of maybe creating a Pull Request then accepting (both of which you can do via the API) but this creates noise (Pull Requests being created and destroyed) and just doesn't seem right.

Is there any way to do this via the API?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't have the inside scoop on this, so this might be a miss-feature that will be removed at some point. Until then:

GitHub makes available all commits across (I assume) the entire fork network; So APIs that accept commit hashes will be happy to work on hashes from the upstream, or across other forks (This is explicitly documented for [repos/commits/compare](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) and [creating a pull requst](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)).

So there are a couple of ways to update via APIs only:

1. Using [Git data api](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/): This will usually be the best option, if you don't change your fork's master.

   1. Get upstream ref `/repos/upstream/repo/git/refs/heads/master`, and get the hash from it
   2. Update your fork PATCH `/repos/my/repo/git/refs/heads/master` with the same hash.
2. Using a higher-level [merge API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/): This will create a merge commit, which some people like.

   1. Get the upstream ref like before
   2. Create a merge to branch `master` in your repo.
3. Pull-request to yourself and merge it via API: This will end up creating not only a merge commit, but a PR as well.

   1. Create PR: POST to `/repos/your/repo/pulls` with `head = "upstream:master"`
   2. Get the PR URL from the response,
   3. Merge it: PUT to `/repos/your/repo/pulls/number/merge`

It's possible that the "upstream:master" notation would also work for options 1 & 2, saving an API call.

Comment: Thanks! #3 is what I've been doing but I hadn't realised #1 was possible and it fits my needs much better (it's always going to be a fast forward commit)

Comment: @ThomasParslow any luck on getting this working, if so can you post this script without any sensitive information ofcourse

Comment: Here's the project I was using it on, it's MIT licensed so help yourself :) https://github.com/almost/hubbub

Comment: I try the #1 and unfortunately there SHA aren't shared from the `upstream` to the source. I guess also #2 has the same issue.
The only one option left is #3

Comment: #1 does 100% work. I didn't try PATCH specifically, but creating a new ref that references a SHA from the source repo works.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible in the GitHub API; [documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branches?apiVersion=2022-11-28#sync-a-fork-branch-with-the-upstream-repository), and [announcement here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-03-api-to-sync-fork-with-upstream/).

In summary, make a POST request to `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/merge-upstream` with the proper authentication and the payload of `{ "branch": "branch-name" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible currently, but I've gone ahead and added that to our API wishlist. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sure it does. The question was "is there any way to do this via the API". The answer is "no".

Comment: @DavidFaber My answer wasn't a critique or request for clarification. As far as I know -- that's not possible via the GitHub API, and I _did_ mention this request to the API team (I work at GitHub).

Comment: It maybe wasn't the answer I was hoping for but it is the correct answer. Accepting it now, thanks! (also, any idea when this might make it off the wishlist and into the API?)

Comment: @ThomasParslow I'd _expect_ that to happen when such an ability is available via the Web UI as well. But I can't make any promises or discuss timelines. (Still, I don't expect that feature to be available in the near future).

Comment: Thanks @IvanZuzak, that's good to know. I'll plan accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This that work for me, because I needed update from upstream but without a merge request commit. My ref is `master`.

1. Create a pull request `POST /repos/:myUsername/:myRepo/pulls`

   - `INPUT: {title, head: 'ownerFromUpStream:master', base: 'master', ...}`
2. Get `sha` from pull request (ex. `response.data.head.sha`)
3. `PATCH /repos/:myUsername/:myRepo/git/refs/master`

   - `PARAMS: {sha: shaFromPullRequest}`

DOC.

- [Update ref](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference)
- [Create pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)