# Is it possible to add a remote with GitHub API?

Tags: api, github

Is it possible to add a remote with GitHub API same as `git remote add upstream <repository URL>`? I have read the docs but I can not find the way.

**ref**
- [How to update a fork from it's original via the Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846667/how-to-update-a-fork-from-its-original-via-the-github-api/27762278#27762278)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get original hash
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/:original/:repo/git/refs/heads/master"

# Follow upstrem change
curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
     --data '{"base":"<fork/BRANCH>","head":"<original/HASH>"}' \
     "https://api.github.com/repos/:fork/:repo/test_project/merges"
```